# what to add to my container ioc ? php

Tags: php, design-patterns, containers, inversion-of-control

i create my own container, i made"bind" method that get "string $alias" and "Closure $closure". the method bind the alias to the object on the $container array , like that:

```
public function bind(string $alias,$closure)
{
    $this->container[$alias] = $closure();
}
```

The second method is "call", that simply call to some instance from the $container. Of course first the method check if the given alias exists, and if doesnt throw an exception

```
public function call(string $alias)
{
    if(array_key_exists($alias,$this->container))
        return $this->container[$alias];
    throw new \Exception();
}
```

is that good ? what more i need to add ? cause i saw on laravel for example that the container is full of method and props, and i dont know why. its just bind and call, isnt ?

Comment: I'd personally save the closure and call it on demand rather than on bind. On one hand you may not need all bound objects during a single call so you're saving on resource allocation, on the other hand, the state of the bound object may depend on when it's called rather on when its bound.

Comment: why i need to save the closure ? what i can do with it ?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to do the following:

**Bind**

```
public function bind(string $alias,$closure)
{
    $this->container[$alias] = $closure;
}
```

**Call (new instance per call)**

```
public function call(string $alias)
{
    if(array_key_exists($alias,$this->container)) {
        $closure = $this->container[$alias];
        return $closure();
    }
    throw new \Exception();
}
```

**Call (singleton behaviour)**

```
public function call(string $alias)
{ 
    if (array_key_exists($alias,$this->instanceContainer)) {
        return $this->instanceContainer[$alias];
    }        
    if(array_key_exists($alias,$this->container)) {
        $closure = $this->container[$alias];
        $this->instanceContainer[$alias] = $closure();
        return $this->instanceContainer[$alias];
    }
    throw new \Exception();
}
```

Which one of the two implementations you pick for the call will depend on your needs. If you need to call the function only once per object go for the second one. You could also have 2 methods: `bind` and `bindSingleton` to differentiate the two different binding types.

There are two main reasons I recommend this:

1. The object is generated on demand, which means that if you bind 1000 objects but only use 10 you'll only create 10 objects.
2. The result of the `$closure()` method may be different based on the time it was called. For example, if you want to instantiate an object which contains a time-stamp, instantiating it on call rather than on bind is more reasonable.

Comment: and $instanceContainer use for singletone bindings?

Comment: and you can give example for things ill need to singleton and things i dont need ?

Comment: If you have a function that creates the database connection then that's typically singleton since you'll be creating it once and using it everywhere. If you have a function that would e.g. generate an instance of a model based on a database entry then you'd need to make a new instance each time since you may need a different database entry to be initialized.

Comment: i also thought about delete bindSingleton and change callSingleton to an argument on call method : call($alias,$shared)